# Name the SciFi book where a person finds a crash-landed alien mech/ship

Tags: story-identification, novel, aliens, young-adult

I remember when I was young really enjoying a SciFi book that I found in a closet of a house that we moved into in the late 80s - early 90s.

What I remember is it being about a kid or person who finds a crash landed alien mech. I don't think it was a very long book so it may have been meant for tweens or just a short story.

Comment: Can you give any more information?

Comment: I think I'm looking for the same book. It's a repair suit with an alien inside. It's not The Iron Giant, nor is it The Man Who Fell to Earth (but I keep thinking that the title is similar).

Comment: What is a "mech"?

Comment: @Gerry That sounds quite familiar! Do you remember if it was a kid that came upon the suit? Definitely not The Iron Giant but my brain just refuses to conjure further...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"The Fallen Spaceman" by Lee Harding ?

Answered on this thread :

[Name of the SciFi book where boy finds a crash-landed robot spaceship](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/84208/name-of-the-scifi-book-where-boy-finds-a-crash-landed-robot-spaceship)

Comment: It would help if you explain why you think this is the answer, and what points match the description in the question.

Comment: Yes! I think this may be it! I'll have to get a copy, but the boy climbing inside is part that really stands out to me.

Comment: Reading the review on Amazon, this is definitely it. It conjured my memory of the prose and specifically how I felt when it was describing the alien having trouble breathing the thick atmosphere.

Answer (score 11):

Maybe it's the book [The Iron Man](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Iron_Man_%28novel%29) from which the film [The Iron Giant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Iron_Giant) was made.

Answer (score 3):

For some reason this reminded me of 
[*The Lost Star* by *Helen Mary Hoover*](http://books.google.dk/books/about/The_lost_star.html?id=V3PEeU62P9sC&redir_esc=y).

Answer (score 1):

Animorphs? A boy finds a crashed ship with an alien inside, and receives the ability to change into any animal he touches.  It was a really short novel, but part of a longer series.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but I read a story in an anthology in the 70s which had a story about a guy called Dan Henry who found a crashed alien craft floating in the surf. While he tried like crazy to salvage it, another alien ship arrived and lifted it by a tractor beam. Dan Henry wouldn't give up his find and got taken up with the wreck. The story was titled "The Edge of the Sea."  Can't recall the author.

Comment: http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/se.cgi?arg=the+edge+of+the+sea&type=Fiction+Titles

Comment: Is this intended to be an answer to the question?