# Name of the SciFi book where boy finds a crash-landed robot spaceship

Tags: story-identification, robots, childrens-novel, soft-sci-fi

I am looking for the author / title of a short illustrated story about a robot (humanoid form) that crash-landed on planet earth and a boy finds the wreck. He climbs into it and goes up to the head and meets with the alien kid. Shortly after, the "mother" robot finds and rescues the stranded robot and the story ends.

The robot's control station is the "head".

I remember the cover having a yellow border and depicting in a grey tones a forest. In the centre of the cover there is a golden humanoid robot wreck, mainly the "face" is shown.

The book should be of the mid-80s and no more that 25-75 pages with a couple of illustrations and in english language.

Comment: I think [this guy](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1658/name-the-scifi-book-where-a-person-finds-a-crash-landed-alien-mech-ship) was looking for the same book, but it was never IDed, so....

Comment: Darn, found a [very good description](http://www.librarything.com/topic/158602) from someone who was looking for this in the past, but still no id....

Comment: Trish Ling: 
http://www.librarything.com/topic/158602
**Definitely** the same book...

Comment: I'm trying to find out the same book, and I keep getting referred to either The Iron Giant or The Man Who Fell to Earth - both not it.

Comment: @talassio If that librarything.com topic is the same book, why not edit your question and quote (with a link) to the contents of that post in your question so as to give more details.

Comment: I want to say it had the word "Fall" in the title. Like "Earthfall", "Skyfall", or "Starfall." The yellow border description of the title sounds like one of Scholastic's Apple Paperbacks.
D20, I remember that book exactly as you describe it, and I've been searching for its identity for years. Maybe one day...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Name the SciFi book where a person finds a crash-landed alien mech/ship](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1658/name-the-scifi-book-where-a-person-finds-a-crash-landed-alien-mech-ship)

Comment: @joshperry It's probably not a good idea to close this question as a dupe of another question whose accepted answer is essentially a link back to *this* question. I've done the dupe-closure the other way round instead.

Comment: Yeah, sounds good @Randal'Thor. Figured there should be only one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The book is *[The Fallen Spaceman](https://www.kirkusreviews.com/book-reviews/lee-harding/the-fallen-spaceman/)* by Lee Harding.

[image: The Fallen Spaceman cover]

> Australian sf writer Harding, author of last year's paranormal YA novel Misplaced Persons, has come up with a clear-cut, dramatic predicament that kids can relate to: inside a giant computerized spacesuit, accidentally hurled to Earth, is tiny spaceman Tyro--and imprisoned with him by accident is a young boy, Erik. The spacesuit, its computer awry, is out of control and in danger of coming apart; Tyro can't survive on the air outside, Erik can't survive on the air within. But: the route to this genuine dilemma is via lots and lots of prosy exposition and rumination; Erik figures chiefly as an innocent victim--the object first of his father's concern, then of Tyro's; and it's not until page 57 (30 pages before the end) that we actually get into the spacesuit with him and witness his discovery of tiny Tyro--not a fearsome giant but his ""brother in distress."" (Before, there's much ado about siezing the giant spaceman and rescuing Erik.) The ending is tense, but also bathetic and preachy--and again none of Erik's doing: with the rampaging spacesuit finally stuck in a lake, Tyro helps Erik escape into the air. a noble sacrifice interrupted at the very last moment by the miraculous appearance of a starship come to rescue him. The people on Earth aren't all warlike, he ruminates; ""in their children there was hope for a happier world."" Virtually all of this, in short, is written from the outside--as a story told rather self-consciously to children. It's also presented in a flat 7fl x 8 3/4 format for younger children who may not have the patience to wait through the preliminaries for the action to be joined.

Comment: Welcome to SFF:SE. Can you explain how this book matches what the OP is asking?

Comment: I found the book because my mother kept EVERYthing we had as a kid. The answer is the fallen spaceman!

Comment: OK, but can you point to any details from the book which match up with the question? That is the sort of answer we look for here.

Comment: The writer is Lee Harding